# App Crash on setRightButton. No idea why

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, crash-reports

I trying to figure out why my App crashes sometimes on costumers devices. My App is from the AppStore. It happend not always, only in rare cases it seams.

Here is the used codeblock

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^(void){ [self.spinner setAlpha:0.0]; } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if(self.spinner != nil){
    [self.spinner removeFromSuperview];
    self.spinner = nil;
        UIBarButtonItem *externButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(openBrowser)];        
        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:externButton animated:YES];
    }
}];
```

It crashes on setRightBarButtomItem:animated:. The codeblock is executed in an Background-Thread. Is that the Problem?

Here the crashlog:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         [THE APP] [3052]
Path:            (null)
Identifier:      [THE APP]
Version:         3.9.0 (3.9.0)
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-11-09 16:07:04.000 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.0 (11A465)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x7000000c
Crashed Thread:  13

Thread 0:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x30781224 __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 1160
1   CoreFoundation                  0x306dbf38 CFStringCreateWithBytes + 48
2   Foundation                      0x310c49e8 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:] + 100
3   Foundation                      0x310c4968 +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] + 124
4   Foundation                      0x310c48b0 NSStringFromClass + 128
5   UIKit                           0x32fddb68 +[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo _customizableClassInfoForViewClass:withGuideClass:] + 260
6   UIKit                           0x32fddd90 -[_UIAppearanceCustomizableClassInfo _superClassInfo] + 160
7   UIKit                           0x32fddcc8 existingAppearancesNodesInNodeForClassAndSuperclasses + 136
8   UIKit                           0x32fdd1d0 +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:] + 164
9   UIKit                           0x32fdd120 +[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:] + 24
10  UIKit                           0x32f32488 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 176
11  QuartzCore                      0x32bb9f40 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 140
12  QuartzCore                      0x32bb5760 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 344
13  UIKit                           0x32f47410 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 532
14  UIKit                           0x32fe9810 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIStatic) _leftRightImagePaddingForEdgeMarginInNavBarIsMini:] + 360
15  UIKit                           0x32fcf140 -[UINavigationBar _getTitleViewFrame:leftViewFrames:rightViewFrames:forItemAtIndex:returnedIdealWidthOfTextContent:availableLayoutWidthForTextContent:idealBackButtonWidth:] + 2504
16  UIKit                           0x32fc6e38 -[UINavigationBar _getTitleViewFrame:leftViewFrames:rightViewFrames:forItemAtIndex:] + 632
17  UIKit                           0x32fc6bb8 -[UINavigationBar _getTitleViewFrame:leftViewFrames:rightViewFrames:] + 136
18  UIKit                           0x32fcd080 -[UINavigationBar _setLeftViews:rightViews:] + 1248
19  UIKit                           0x32fca2b8 -[UINavigationBar _pushNavigationItem:transition:] + 464
20  UIKit                           0x32fc9e98 __71-[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]_block_invoke + 148
21  UIKit                           0x32fe13a0 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
22  UIKit                           0x32fe0fe8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
23  UIKit                           0x32fe0f78 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
24  UIKit                           0x32f32530 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 344
25  QuartzCore                      0x32bb9f40 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 140
26  QuartzCore                      0x32bb5760 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 344
27  QuartzCore                      0x32bb55f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
28  QuartzCore                      0x32bb5008 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
29  QuartzCore                      0x32bb4e18 CA::Transaction::commit() + 308
30  QuartzCore                      0x32baeb48 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 52
31  CoreFoundation                  0x30777f70 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
32  CoreFoundation                  0x307758f8 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 280
33  CoreFoundation                  0x30775c48 __CFRunLoopRun + 736
34  CoreFoundation                  0x306e0540 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
35  CoreFoundation                  0x306e0320 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
36  GraphicsServices                0x354172e8 GSEventRunModal + 136
37  UIKit                           0x32f971e0 UIApplicationMain + 1132
38  [THE APP]                            0x00059f48 main (main.m:21)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b043838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3af8c640 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 36

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b043a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30777560 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 156
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30775c80 __CFRunLoopRun + 792
3   CoreFoundation                  0x306e0540 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x306e0320 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
5   Foundation                      0x3111b650 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 320
6   Foundation                      0x31190dc0 __NSThread__main__ + 1056
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcc58 _pthread_body + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcbc8 _pthread_start + 96

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056550 __semwait_signal + 24
1   Foundation                      0x311904d8 +[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:] + 144
2   [THE APP]                            0x0014a870 -[KSCrashDeadlockMonitor runMonitor] + 232
3   Foundation                      0x31190dc0 __NSThread__main__ + 1056
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcc58 _pthread_body + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcbc8 _pthread_start + 96

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b043a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   [THE APP]                            0x001469e0 ksmachexc_i_handleExceptions + 128
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcc58 _pthread_body + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcbc8 _pthread_start + 96

Thread 9:

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcc58 _pthread_body + 136
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcbc8 _pthread_start + 96

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b056c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8

Thread 13 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aaa1b66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   UIKit                           0x32fe4b80 -[UINavigationItem updateNavigationBarButtonsAnimated:] + 156
2   UIKit                           0x32fe46e8 -[UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:animated:] + 156
3   [THE APP]                            0x000c6058 -[ProductViewController loadXML] (ProductViewController.m:978)
4   Foundation                      0x31190dc0 __NSThread__main__ + 1056
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcc58 _pthread_body + 136
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b0bcbc8 _pthread_start + 96

Thread 13 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x15e78c40     r1: 0x33517435     r2: 0x00000000     r3: 0x00000000 
    r4: 0x33517435     r5: 0x33530ea0     r6: 0x15e83b00     r7: 0x037a2be0 
    r8: 0x15d56570     r9: 0x70000000    r10: 0x00000000    r11: 0x00000001 
    ip: 0x3b5be224     sp: 0x037a27f0     lr: 0x32fccffb     pc: 0x3aaa1b66 
  cpsr: 0x20000030 

Binary Images:
[cut cause of char limit]
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: UIKit is not meant to be communicated with on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't run this in a background thread.
Secondly BAD_ACCESS usually happens when you over-release something.

I can't figure out where you over-release but maybe you can find it in your code. my guess is the navigation item tries to release something before setting your externButton...

EDIT: where is this code happening at? could be that the UIViewController isn't pushed anymore into the navigation controller or not the top one by the time this code is executed?

Comment: will it help, when i try it like this?

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
  [CODE]
 });`

Comment: I load data for the view per xml directly after viewDidLoad and when the data is loaded i want to change the spinner to an externButton

Answer (score 0):

Things that update the UI should be on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* UI code goes here */ });
```